# Process Isolation in Python

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, multiprocessing, isolation

I'm aware of using the `subprocess` module to isolate functions that might segfault. This works:

```
import subprocess
# Blocking for simplicity
res = subprocess.check_output(["python", "c_library_wrapper.py", arg0, arg1, ...])
```

What I'm trying to figure out is why `multiprocessing` doesn't have the same effect. This doesn't seem to work:

```
import multiprocessing
from c_library_wrapper import f
# Assume that f puts the return value into a shared queue
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(arg0, arg1, ...))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Isn't this also creating an independent process? Is there a core concept I'm missing here?

**Background:** I'm isolating a large third-party C library to protect against segfaults. I know that the best way to handle segfaults is to fix them, but this library is *really* big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention you are using a shared queue. Heed the warning in [the docs of `Process.terminate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) (termination via segfault is a similar situation):

> **Warning:** If this method is used when the associated process is using a
>   pipe or queue then the pipe or queue is liable to become corrupted and
>   may become unusable by other process. Similarly, if the process has
>   acquired a lock or semaphore etc. then terminating it is liable to
>   cause other processes to deadlock.

Comment: Thanks! After simplifying my shared queue logic, the multiprocessing approach worked as expected.